# jQuery - Do action when all ajax have completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've read about the jQuery's `Deferred` object, but I can't seem to make much sense out of it, here's my problem, I've got the following code:

```
function preprocess(form) {
    $(form).find(".input input").each(function() {
        var required = $(this).attr("required");
        var checkField = $(this).closest(".inputcontainer").children(".check");
        var errorField = $(this).closest(".inputcontainer").children(".errormessage");
        if (typeof required !== 'undefined') {
            $(checkField).each(function() {
                $(this).css("color", "#FFFF00");
                $(this).html("&#x2718;");
            });
            $(errorField).each(function() {
                $(this).css("color", "#FFFF00");
                $(this).html("(Required)");
            });
        }
        else {
            $(checkField).each(function() {
                $(this).css("color", "#FFFF00");
                $(this).html("&#x2714;");
            });
            $(errorField).each(function() {
                $(this).css("color", "#000000");
                $(this).html("");
            });
        }
    });

    $(form).find("datalist").each(function() {
        var datalist = $(this);
        callService({
            name: "datalist_" + $(this).attr("id"),
            data: { },
            success: function(json) {
                $(json).each(function() {
                    var html = "";
                    $(this.options).each(function() {
                        html += "<option value='" + this.value + "'>";
                    });
                    $(datalist).append(html);
                });
            }
        });
    });

    $(form).find("select").each(function() {
        var select = $(this);
        callService({
            name: "select_" + $(this).attr("name"),
            data: { },
            success: function(json) {
                $(json).each(function() {
                    var html = "";
                    $(this.options).each(function() {
                        html += "<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.value + "</option>";
                    });
                    $(select).append(html);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This code prepares a form to be ready to be presented to the user, which involves AJAX calls, which I have wrapped in a `callService({});` call, what you can see is the following:

- It checks input and puts possibly `(Required)` next to the fields. (No AJAX)
- It loads options from `<datalist>` and `<select>`s dynamically. (AJAX)

Then I also have the following (simplified):

```
function setContent(html, url) {
    html = $.parseHTML(html);
    $(html).filter("form").each(function() {
        preprocess($(this));
    });
    $("#pagemain").html(html);
}
```

This gets `html` from an AJAX call, then calls `preprocess` on all its forms and updates the `#pagemain`.
However now data is being displayed **before** the `preprocess` has completely finished.

**The question:** How can I do the `$("#pagemain").html(html);` after `preprocessed` ánd involving AJAX processes, have been finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function preprocess(form) {
    //Your above code is omitted for brevity
    var promises = [];

    $(form).find("datalist").each(function() {
        var defered = $.Deferred();//create a defered object
        promises.push(defered.promise());//store the promise to the list to be resolved later

        var datalist = $(this);
        callService({
            name: "datalist_" + $(this).attr("id"),
            data: { },
            success: function(json) {
                $(json).each(function() {
                    var html = "";
                    $(this.options).each(function() {
                        html += "<option value='" + this.value + "'>";
                    });
                    $(datalist).append(html);
                });
                defered.resolve();//resolve the defered when ajax call has finished
            }
        });
    });

    $(form).find("select").each(function() {
        var defered = $.Deferred();//create a defered object
        promises.push(defered.promise());//store the promise to the list to be resolved later
        var select = $(this);
        callService({
            name: "select_" + $(this).attr("name"),
            data: { },
            success: function(json) {
                $(json).each(function() {
                    var html = "";
                    $(this.options).each(function() {
                        html += "<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.value + "</option>";
                    });
                    $(select).append(html);
                });
                defered.resolve();//resolve the defered when ajax call has finished
            }
        });
    });
    return promises;
}
```

Your `setContent`:

```
function setContent(html, url) {
    html = $.parseHTML(html);
    var promises = [];
    $(html).filter("form").each(function() {
        promises = promises.concat(preprocess($(this)));//Concatenating all promises arrays
    });

    $.when.apply($,promises).then(function(){// Use $.when to execute a function when all deferreds are resolved.
        $("#pagemain").html(html);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think your code is clear, however could you post some more explanation of how exactly the `Deferred` objects interact with my solution?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, also I've implemented it on my site and it's instantly working, so a +1 for that! I'll try to work out my second use case for this myself.

Comment: @skiwi: I recommend that you should also care for ajax errors by calling defered.reject() in error callback and you can pass a second callback to $.when to do something when there is an ajax error.

Answer (score 1):

Deferred's can be a little intimidating to learn at first, but, like most things, once the light bulb goes on and you get it, it's pretty simple. The simple setup for creating a deferred object is like this:

```
var defer = $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
 // do the processing you need, and then...
 // when processing is complete, make a call to...
 dfd.resolve(/* return data goes here, if required */);
}).promise();

// use the deferred object like it was an ajax call
defer.then(/* do the stuff that needed to wait */);
```

So, using your example:

```
function setContent(html, url) {
  html = $.parseHTML(html);

  var defer = $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    $(html).filter("form").each(function() {
      preprocess($(this));
    });

    dfd.resolve();
  }).promise();

  defer.then($("#pagemain").html(html));
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it's correct, but I'm still unable to grasp this solution completely. The solution of @KhanhTO may be a bit more explicit, but that one I can fully grasp by now.

Answer (score 0):

neat solution will be using when :

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
    $.when( {//your preprocessing function here
 } ).done(function( x ) {
      //your done action here
    });
```